# How to create a "sub-package" within a package in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, javascript-import

Let's say I have a package called `dog`, and it exports some functions defined in `index.js`. The `index.js` file is kept inside of a `src` directory. Here's what the tree looks like:

```
--> dog
   --> src
      --> index.js
```

Importing a function from the `dog` package would look like this: `import { eat } from '@dog'`

Now I would like to create a "sub-package" (called `puppy`) of the `dog` package. I want the import to look like this:

```
import { whimper } from '@dog/puppy'`
```

I'm wondering how to structure the `dog` package so that I can import the `puppy` package in the manner shown above. I've tried a couple different ways without much success. Here are some examples of what I tried:

Attempt 1:

```
--> dog
   --> puppy
      --> index.js
   --> src
      --> index.js
```

Attempt 2:

```
--> dog
   --> src
      --> puppy
         --> index.js
      --> index.js
```

These result in an error about being unable to resolve `@dog/puppy` when trying to import functions from the module.

Just FYI, I'm not all that familiar with creating packages. I don't even understand how `import { eat } from @dog` works without specifying the full path to `eat` (dog/src/index.js).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a solution to my question.

I can actually utilize the "Attempt 1" directory structure above:

```
--> dog
   --> puppy
      --> index.js
   --> src
      --> index.js
```

The part I was missing was changing the command I was using to run the `dog` module locally. I'm using `chokidar` and `yalc` to watch/publish changes made to the `dog` module, and I needed to tweak the command to include changes made within the `puppy` directory. Prior to this, I think the `puppy` code was essentially being ignored, and thus not being published by `yalc`. So the code that wanted to import the `puppy` functions was not able to find it.

Comment: Hi! Can you add more info about your solution?